# IE 11 not handling .sort() method by date in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, sorting

Really unsure what's going on so if anyone could point me in the right direction with this, it would be much appreciated!

Basically I have an array of data that all have a `CreatedDate`, I've sorted these with a function in Angular 4 to display by the `CreatedDate`.
This works absolutely fine in every browser except IE, where it just displays them in any order it fancies.

```
 var sorting = function (data: myArray[]) {
                        return data.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.CreatedDate).getTime() - new Date(a.CreatedDate).getTime());
                    }
```

I thought this could be something to do with the polyfills, but nope!

Here's my data array:

```
0: {attributes: {…}, Name: "name1", CreatedDate: "2018-12-05T11:30:01.000+0000", …}
1: {attributes: {…}, Name: "name2", CreatedDate: "2018-10-01T14:19:52.000+0000", …}
2: {attributes: {…}, Name: "name3", CreatedDate: "2018-07-25T12:52:55.000+0000", …}
3: {attributes: {…}, Name: "name4", CreatedDate: "2018-07-05T12:37:09.000+0000", …}
4: {attributes: {…}, Name: "name5", CreatedDate: "2018-07-04T11:06:04.000+0000", …}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: Please share the `CreatedDate` format. You can provide `data` array as well.

Comment: You need to return `-1`, `0` or `1`. Then the sorting will work. Please post your array's data.

Comment: Added `data` array above :)

Comment: IE11 `new Date("2018-12-05T11:30:01.000+0000")` -> `Invalid Date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE 11 do not support date string whose timezone doesn't contain colon. (Although it is valid ISO 8601) And `new Date("2018-12-05T11:30:01.000+0000")` would be parsed into `Invalid Date`.

If your date strings are guaranteed to be ended with `+0000` you may replace them by `Z` like this: `new Date(b.CreatedDate.replace(/\+0000$/, 'Z')).getTime()`. If not, you may want some third party datetime libraries to handle the date parsing.

Also, you may chose switching to another datetime syntax, such as unix timestamp, if both front-end and back-end are under your control.

Comment: Legend! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

follow this link [Differential Loading](https://dev.to/lacolaco/differential-loading-a-new-feature-of-angular-cli-v8-4jl) it may be useful if you using Angular 8.

this is usually the issue with some browsers not knowing how to handle ES6 code.
read this article it may be useful [You might not need to transpile your JavaScript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/you-might-not-need-to-transpile-your-javascript-4d5e0a438ca/)